# In Terminator Genisys, why doesn't this character kill Sarah and Kyle when he has the chance?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series, terminator-genisys

In *Terminator Genisys*, when Sarah and Kyle go forward in time to 2017, they end up getting arrested by the police and such.

> Who they think is John Connor ends up "rescuing" them, only to have it become clear that he's actually working with/for Skynet. The Arnold Terminator, their real friend, then rescues them from *him*, and they escape.

He (the aforementioned non-Terminator character) then spends the rest of the movie seemingly trying to catch and kill them. It doesn't seem like he is just trying to catch them alive, as he does a lot of stuff in the process that could easily kill them.

So my question is, why didn't he kill them before the Terminator was there, when it was just him and Sarah and Kyle? It seems like he could have *easily* destroyed them with no problem, but instead he talked to them for a while and lost his chance.

Comment: Seems a bit counter-intuitive to kill his own parents, as that would cause him to cease to exist?

Comment: @neverendingqs but that's at odds with what he does for the rest of the film, and what he says in the quote kyle jones posted. I figured that this problem was solved by the "split timelines" thing they talked about briefly, so he was somehow independent of them now.

Answer (score 7):

The machine Connor's motives were made clear by this conversation in the parking garage after Connor's machine nature had been revealed.

> **REESE**: What do you want with us?
>
> **CONNOR**: I'm offering us a future.  Together.  A family.
>
> **REESE**: If we refuse?
>
> **CONNOR**: Then you die.

They refused and so Connor was trying to kill them from then on, since he knew they were determined to destroy Skynet.

It may seem odd that a machine version of Connor would want to have a family but not if the old John Connor is still part of the man/machine hybrid.  Perhaps the only way to not go mad from the hybridizing procedure is to accept it and move forward instead of continuing to fight a battle that is hopelessly lost.  Indeed, transhumanism is probably the only endgame where humanity survives in any form after a Singularity type event.

Comment: This  doesn't seem to make sense to me though: why would Skynet want a human "family"?

Comment: @YungHummmma Misdirection. If Kyle and Sarah had given in to the idea of a "family", then they'd be taken out of the game, all the while leaving Skynet free to *not* be beaten by future John Connor.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it. John never had a family. Now, in his nanotech body. His reaching out. If sarah/Kyle accepts then wouldn't John conner be born a human/machine hybrid. Thus, insuring his own hybrid survival.
There's a lot of clues in the film if you look. One being that genesis sent pops + T-1000 back to gain Sarah's trust while insuring Matt smith/skynet survival. Pops was part of the construction crew there. He made a safe place for Sarah. Whose saying he didn't do the same for genesis. Would throw Sarah off the track while it had time to grow.
It's weird how pops could make a time machine while the jonn terminator could only design the part of the machine that ultimately destroyed him. How very convinient. Plus, whose to say that this version of skynet wanted to destroy humans. When, after creating T-3000 John. Would he done the same for the rest of humanity? Then again. Who can blame him for wiping humanity out when all we know is how to destroy eh?!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I think you're saying "... because at first he wants to talk to Sarah."  Which is what the other answer already says.  If you're posting a new answer, you should have something different to add.  Please read [answer].